# Omnet++: Error in module (cModule) SN (id=1) during network setup

Tags: omnet++

I'm trying to run Castalia simulation (radioTest) in Omnet++ but I stopped on one issue. When I'm choosing one of the configurations define in omnetpp.ini then error appear:

**"Error in module (cModule) SN (id=1) during network setup: Class "WirelessChannel" not found -- perhaps its code was not linked in, or the class wasn't registered with Register_Class(), or in the case of modules and channels, with Define_Module()/Define_Channel()."**

I would be very grateful for your help.

Comment: Have you compiled Castalia?

Comment: Yes, I did.    Comments must be at least 15 characters in length.

Comment: Sorry, the second sentence is meaningless - just to add comment. My "extended" sentence was to short :)

Comment: Could you explain how you start simulation: from console or from IDE? Do you use opp_run or CastialBin?

Comment: Dear Jerzy, at the beginning I started simulation from console and it working fine. After that i decided to try it using IDE. I'm using opp_run.

Answer (score 3):

By default `Castalia` is compiled into executable file, so one cannot use `opp_run` to start it. 
 
In `OMNeT++` you should go to `Run` | `Run Configuration...` then add a new configuration by double clicking of `OMNeT++ Simulation`. 
Next set:

- as `Working directory` - the folder, where `omnetpp.ini` of the simulation is placed, e.g. `/Castalia-3.2/Simulations/BANtest`
- as `Executable` set `Other` and indicate your `CastaliaBin` executable file, e.g. `/Castalia-3.2/src/CastaliaBin`
- in `Ini file(s)` type `omnetpp.ini`

and run the simulation.

Comment: And this was the reason. I changed Executable to Other with proply patch and its working now. Jerzy, is it possible to send you private message here and ask few more question?

Comment: Stackoverflow is the place where people *publicly* ask questions, others *publicly* answer them. As a consequence, another person with the same problem may find the solution. So feel free to ask another question in Stackoverflow connected with `OMNeT++` or `Castalia`. P.S. Remember one important rule: one problem in one question.